# Do arrays in C count blanks?

Tags: c

Im learning for my upcoming exam and i wanted to ask if an Array counts blanks.

e.g in the Image below: does he count like the first row?

[image]

Comment: Why are there two 9s?

Comment: In the first and second row
if i would say string + 9, would C tell me that it is "blank" or "i"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blank"? If it's unitilaisied and read, then that invokes ub. Likewise if the element doesn't really exist then that also invokes ub. It would be far easier to help you if you had some code example to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array of characters yes it counts the spaces,
it should be in the 9 position the first blank/space and the first (i) should be in 10 position and etc and in the end of the array should be a /0..

p.s: null is a character also, that gets on the end of the array

Comment: Ok thanks.

Does he count \0 as a character aswell? (I forgot to add it in the last row)

Comment: @Nexitis as the end character of the array yes Strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character '\0'.

Comment: `strlen("foo")` (i.e. the 4 element array `'f', 'o', 'o', '\n'`) will report a length of 3, still the array size is 4.